# The type or namespace name 'UserScopedSettingAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Configuration'

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface

https://neon-dont-feel-pain.000webhostapp.com/unKJn.png - Image uploader

I have a problem with my WPF UI.

I get this error here when building.

I have the `System.Configurations` package installed and `System.Configurations.Install` installed. I don't know if I need to fix it with a line of code or add a **reference**.

Cheers for any responses.

Comment: Maybe you mean "UserScopedSettingAttribute" instead of "UserScopedSettingAttributeAttribute"?

Comment: It is an auto generated file. I didn't change anything in it. Also I don't know what you mean by changing it. The error I said in the title I copied it from the error list.https://neon-dont-feel-pain.000webhostapp.com/ZKknO.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to stackoverflow I don't know how to close a question or mark it as solved etc. I found the answer.

Thanks anyone who replied eitherway. C:

If anyone is looking for the solution cause I'm posting an answer. The problem was I accidently deleted the reference `System`. Sorry for any inconvenience staff :)